# Attaching gameObjects to a moving Mesh by position retrieved from triangle index

Tags: unity, mesh

I am trying to attach GameObjects `testAttach` to triangle indices in `trianglesToAttachTo` on a mesh, call it goMesh. I've identified the triangleIndices I want to attach to from retrieving via `RaycastHit.triangleIndex` but I seem to run into issues like: `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.` I have tried removing the 3 multiplier, but that leads to positions that do not reflect the selected triangle positions.

Super quick test script:

`````
public class AttachToFaceMeshEars : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] testAttach;

    public int[] trianglesToAttachTo = { 1604, 1982 };

    public GameObject goMesh;
     
    void Update()
    {
        Test(goMesh);
    }

    void Test(GameObject g)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < testAttach.Length; i++) AttachTo(g,g.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh, trianglesToAttachTo[i], testAttach[i]);
    }

    void AttachTo(GameObject goMesh,Mesh mesh,int triangle,GameObject go)
    {
        int[] tris = mesh.triangles;
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
        Vector3 p0 = vertices[ 3 * tris[triangle] ];

        go.transform.position = goMesh.transform.TransformPoint(p0);
    }

}

````
`````

Comment: I think it might be `vertices[ tris[ 3*triangle ] ]` instead, no? Because the `mesh.triangles` array is the one that has three entries (vertices) per triangle.

Comment: okay, thanks for that fix! too rusty / too tired atm...

Comment: Looks like you're using Unity — don't forget to tag your question appropriately. Did PepeOjeda's suggestion solve your problem? If so, it should be posted as an Answer to be accepted.

Comment: yes - @pepeojeda feel free to post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `mesh.triangles` array is the one that contains three entries per triangle, the correct way to index a specific vertex would be `vertices[ tris[ 3*triangle ] ]`.